# Apache Tika - Getting Metadata Without Downloading File

Tags: stream, mime-types, content-type, apache-tika

I have been trying to implement an application to determine content type of any file. I use Apache Tika for determination.

Here is a basic code implementation for that:

```
InputStream fileStream = ContentTypeController.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);

Tika tika = new Tika();
String contentType = null;
try {
    contentType = tika.detect(fileStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Instead of code above I have to download files from Openstack to determine file content type. Some files are **more than** **100GB** and downloading all file is heavy.

I can not figure out how to overcome this necessity of downloading all file, I hope you have any idea/solution without downloading all file

Comment: If you want metadata your only option is to give Tika the whole file - metadata can be stored anywhere in the file depending on the type. However, your code isn't doing anything with metadata, so what are you after?

Comment: As @Gagravarr said, you can't reliably get metadata from a partial file. It looks to me, though, that you just want the file type.  If this is so, with one major caveat, you should be able to get the file type with the first 1000 or so bytes.  The major caveat is you can't get "container" files' specific mime types, e.g., if you only use the first 1000 bytes of a docx (a zip-based format), Tika will likely return "application/zip".  You'll need the full file for precise type detection on container formats (zip based and ole2 based), but you should be good to go with pdf, mp4, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Tika has ability to determine content type of file without downloading all if you pass a URL parameter to detect() function.

```
Tika tika = new Tika();
String contentType = null;
try {
    contentType = tika.detect(new URL("a url"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```